# How to track UITouches between two UIViewcontrollers? (using containment)

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uitouch

I have two view controllers appearing on the screen at the same time using view controller containment, implemented the same as in Apple's code example. Call them view controller A (vcA) and view controller B (vcB), and the container view controller (containerVC).

Each vcA and vcB both have a grid of objects, and I want to be able to drag objects from vcA to vcB. More specifically, I want the touch that originates in vcA to hit the touchesMoved:withEvent method in vcB once it is within the bounds vcB.

I have overridden the touchesMoved:withEvent method on the containerVC, track the touch via a hit test, and tried forwarding the touch *down* the UIView hierarchy like so:

```
// in the containerVC
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint locationPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    UIView* touchIsInViewControllerA = [vcA hitTest:locationPoint withEvent:event];
    if (touchIsInViewControllerA) {
        NSLog(@"Touch is in vcA");
        return;
    }
    UIView* touchIsInViewControllerB = [vcB hitTest:locationPoint withEvent:event];
    if (touchIsInViewControllerB) {
        NSLog(@"Touch is in vcB");
        [vcB touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event]; // this causes a crash
    }
}
```

This seems to be recursive, with containerVC pushing the touch event down the hierarchy, then vcB passing the touch event back up the hierarchy.

My question: Is there a way to keep vcB from passing the touch event back up the responder chain to containerVC? Or should I approach this a different way - make vcB a delegate of vcA and leave containerVC out of the equation?

**Note:** I'm guessing a common response will be to give up the VC containment pattern and keep it all in one view controller, but for reasons not shown in this example I think keeping them separate will work better for me - unless it's utter insanity and super hacky to do so...

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved easily by setting individual gesture object for each view controller.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 if (touchIsInViewControllerA) {

// calls a delegate of view controller A

  }
else
 {

// calls a delegate of view controller B
 }
}
```